# PDFClown nuget package cannot load assembly

Tags: c#, pdfclown

I've added the PDFClown nuget package to a .net core project and ran into the following error at runtime:

> Could not load file or assembly 'PDFClown, Version=0.1.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A
>   strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131044)

I'll also note that it build without issue and the problem only appears at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out; apparently it's an unsigned assembly.

You can fix this issue by modifying the SignAssembly tag to false in the .csproj file for the project(s) which added the package. This may be an unsafe change however, so I'm going to raise the issue with the PDFClown devs.